# Adding mean to a histogram in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I created a histogram for the distance variable of the flights data frame in the nycflights13 package.

Now I am trying to add a vertical line to the histogram that marks the mean, like so:

```
library(nycflights13)
attach(flights)
ggplot(flights, aes(x = distance)) +
  geom_histogram(aes(y = ..density..), 
                 color = "darkblue", 
                 fill = "lightblue", 
                 binwidth = 250) +
  labs(x = "Departure delay (minutes)") +
  geom_vline(xintercept = mean(distance, color = black, size = 1.5)) +
  geom_density(color = "red", size = 1)
```

This gives me the output:

```
Warning messages:
1: In mean.default(distance, color = black, size = 1.5) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
2: Removed 1 rows containing missing values (geom_vline).
```

How do I fix this? I tried removing the NA values but I guess not in the correct way.

Comment: Hi Ruud. On my machine the code works fine with no warnings. I'm using ggplot 3.3.0.

Comment: With me, your code works well, without a warning

Comment: Thanks to the both of you I tried cleaning out my workspace. I completely overlooked that. I must have had something loaded that made it go wrong.

Comment: Oh, you didn't close the bracket after mean.

Comment: `xintercept = mean(distance), color = black...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put in the `mean` as a scalar. Thus we can use `$` here. Put in the color as a string `"black"`.

```
library(nycflights13)
# attach(flights)  # I strongly recommend not to use attach
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(flights, aes(x = distance)) +
  geom_histogram(aes(y = ..density..), 
                 color = "darkblue", 
                 fill = "lightblue", 
                 binwidth = 250) +
  labs(x = "Departure delay (minutes)") +
  geom_vline(xintercept = mean(flights$distance),
             color="black", size=1.5) +
  geom_density(color = "red", size = 1)
```

[image]